# Is it possible to get an attribute from an element when using .on() for dynamically loaded content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

On a site that I'm building for someone, I am making most internal links use `pushState` since it is a faster user experience. I'm having a problem with getting the `href` attribute from an anchor `<a>` element that is loaded dynamically. People always tell me to use `.on()` rather than `.live()` because `.live()` is deprecated, but then I run into problems like this.

Here's my code:

```
$('#artists').on('click', '.artist a', function(e) {
        SM.config.loader.show();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        SM.loadContent(href,'artist');
        history.pushState('', 'New URL: ' + href, href);
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

There is no `href` attribute being returned (obviously) so the URL is not changing.

Basically my question is **how do I get the `href` attribute from the element in the second parameter of the `on` event?**

Comment: It should work. There is nothing magically about event delegation or elements that are created dynamically. Once you have a reference to the DOM element (here, `this`) you are sorted. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Your code looks valid, the method you are using to get the href should work. console.log `this` and `this.href` to see which element is triggering the event.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: works fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/jGqrT/

Comment: @Paul I'm using the latest version (`code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`)

Comment: @wirey Hmm, I don't understand why it isn't working on my site though.

Comment: @Nathan Did you look at Paul's answer?  Make sure you're using jQuery 1.7+ if you are using `on`.

Comment: @wirey Yeah, and I even tried alerting it and logging it in the console but it isn't working so I don't think it is even binding to `.artist a` but I don't see why it wouldn't, there is nothing stopping it from binding, and it is the correct selector.

Comment: change your `on` to `delegate` to see if it works.  $('#artists').delegate('.artist a','click', function(e)

Comment: @wirey It still didn't work... I tried `live` and it works, so I don't know why `on` won't work.

Comment: Wait a second. I just realized that `#artists` is being loaded with ajax, too. Whoops, I feel really dumb right now LOL. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NcZ22/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="artists"></div>​
```

**JS**

```
//Bind an event
$('#artists').on('click', '.artist', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(href);
});​

//Add the element to the dom
$('<a />', {
    href: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    text: 'SO',
    class: 'artist'
}).appendTo('#artists');
```

Also, make sure you are using jQuery 1.7+ You can read more about `.on` vs `.delegate` here http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Simple comparison of syntax:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: The weird thing is that it is not even even binding because the alert isn't happening so something is wrong.

Comment: JavaScript can be difficult to debug. I would recommend commenting out a large chunk of your code and just leave the raw event binding. Get that to work then uncomment each other line/block one at a time till you find the bug.

Comment: I found the problem, and it was the simplest and right in front of my eyes. It was that `#artists` was also being loaded with ajax, so it wasn't there when I was binding it with `on` and was therefore never binded. Thanks for your help.